# AWK: I have 2 input files. Can I made 1 common script to get output in a CSV format by (AWK)?

Tags: regex, awk

Hellow Everybody,

There are 2 files that I need to process (input_all.txt) or (input_deatils.txt), I'd like to process them by one common AWK script.

The script (data.awk), which i tried to use to get the output as in table format CSV.

If i try to use the code as shown

```
        awk -f data.awk input_all.txt > output.txt

  or 

        awk -f data.awk input_details.txt > output.txt
```

Here is the code (data.awk) I tried to use  (I need help to fix this code ):

```
BEGIN {
          split("Node,Boards,Deactive,DEFAULT,PRIO,GRP,LOAD",array,",");
          print_array1(array);
       }

     /^Node     Boards   Deactive/  { getline     
        { while (/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+/ && (NF>1) == 1)
           {  array[1]=(substr($0,1,7))
              array[2]=(substr($0,10,7))
              array[3]=(substr($0,18,10))
              array[4]=(substr($0,34,7))
              array[5]=(substr($0,45,9))
              array[6]=(substr($0,55,7))
              array[6]=(substr($0,64,7))
              print_array1(array)
              getline }
           }
        }

 function print_array1(array)
 {
     printf("%-9s", array[1])
     printf("%-9s", array[2])
     printf("%-12s", array[3])
     printf("%-9s", array[4])
     printf("%-11s", array[5])
     printf("%-9s", array[6])
     printf("%-5s", array[7])
     printf("\n");
     #for(item=2;item<=6;item++){array[item]=""}
  }
```

The input files  can be one as one of the following formats.
  The first format can be as shown (input_all.txt)

```
     display:all;
 BOARDS STATES IN NODES

 Node     Boards   Deactive       DEFAULT    PRIO      GRP      LOAD
 TSTS950  S950

 2CGBMW1  S854
          S857
          S852
          S855
          S853

 BM311    BM311    DEACTIVE  

 BM310    BM310    DEACTIVE  

 ENA5                                        PER BD    S850       10
                                                       S852       22
                                                       S854       1
                                                       T850       17
                                                       T851       59
                                                       T852       1
                                                       2S50       44

 SMDRUH   S852                                         S852
          S855                                         S855
          S854                                         S854
          S857                                         S857
          S850
          S851
          S856
          S853

 MAINBRD  S850                      DEFAULT
          S851
          S856
          S853
          BM310
          S950
          T751
          S855
          T859
          S857
          T851

 END
```

The 2nd input format can be as  (Input_details.txt)

```
     display:TSTS950   ;
 BOARDS STATES IN NODES

 Node     Boards   Deactive       DEFAULT    PRIO      GRP      LOAD
 TSTS950  S950

 END

 display:2CGBMW1   ;
 BOARDS STATES IN NODES

 Node     Boards   Deactive       DEFAULT    PRIO      GRP      LOAD
 2CGBMW1  SXSZ
          SXSZ
          SXSZ
          SXSZ
          SXSZ

 END

 display:BM311   ;
 BOARDS STATES IN NODES

 Node     Boards   Deactive       DEFAULT    PRIO      GRP      LOAD
 BM311    BM311    DEACTIVE  

 END

 display:BM310 ;
 BOARDS STATES IN NODES

 Node     Boards   Deactive       DEFAULT    PRIO      GRP      LOAD
 BM310    BM310    DEACTIVE   

 END

 display:S850   ;
 BOARDS STATES IN NODES

 Node     Boards   Deactive       DEFAULT    PRIO      GRP      LOAD
 S850     S850     DEACTIVE

 END

 display:ENA5   ;
 BOARDS STATES IN NODES

 Node     Boards   Deactive       DEFAULT    PRIO      GRP      LOAD
 ENA5                                        PER BD    S850       10
                                                       S852       22
                                                       S854       1
                                                       T850       17
                                                       T851       59
                                                       T852       1
                                                       2S50       44
 END

 display:SMDRUH;
 BOARDS STATES IN NODES

 Node     Boards   Deactive       DEFAULT    PRIO      GRP      LOAD
 SMDRUH   S852                                         S852
          S855                                         S855
          S854                                         S854
          S857                                         S857
          S850
          S851
          S856
          S853

 END

 display:MAINBRD   ;
 BOARDS STATES IN NODES

 Node     Boards   Deactive       DEFAULT    PRIO      GRP      LOAD
 MAINBRD  S850                    DEFAULT
          S851
          S856
          S853
          BM310
          S950
          T751
          S855
          T859
          S857
          T851

 END
```

The output required should as shown (output.txt).

```
  Node     Boards   Deactive       DEFAULT    PRIO      GRP      LOAD
  TSTS950  S950
  2CGBMW1  SXSZ
  2CGBMW1  SXSZ
  2CGBMW1  SXSZ
  2CGBMW1  SXSZ
  2CGBMW1  SXSZ
  BM311    BM311    DEACTIVE  
  BM310    BM310    DEACTIVE   
  ENA5                                        PER BD    S850       10
  ENA5                                        PER BD    S852       22
  ENA5                                        PER BD    S854       1
  ENA5                                        PER BD    T850       17
  ENA5                                        PER BD    T851       59
  ENA5                                        PER BD    T852       1
  ENA5                                        PER BD    2S50       44
  SMDRUH   S852                                         S852
  SMDRUH   S855                                         S855
  SMDRUH   S854                                         S854
  SMDRUH   S857                                         S857
  SMDRUH   S850
  SMDRUH   S851
  SMDRUH   S856
  SMDRUH   S853
  MAINBRD  S850                    DEFAULT
  MAINBRD  S851                    DEFAULT
  MAINBRD  S856                    DEFAULT
  MAINBRD  S853                    DEFAULT
  MAINBRD  BM310                   DEFAULT
  MAINBRD  S950                    DEFAULT
  MAINBRD  T751                    DEFAULT
  MAINBRD  S855                    DEFAULT
  MAINBRD  T859                    DEFAULT
  MAINBRD  S857                    DEFAULT
  MAINBRD  T851                    DEFAULT
```

Now the code (data.awk) is not working to generate the output. Can someone help me to correct and modify the code please?

Comment: Please, explain what your code is intended to do

Comment: 0@Jdamian: The code is trying to find the lines between (^Node     Boards   Deactive) and (END). Each time we found them, The 1st line is the reference line. By adding the values of $1 for each record. Also, it will add $3,$4,$5&$7 if they were existed in the reference line. Then putting the data on column CSV format.

Comment: @Jdamian: The code is trying to find the lines between (^Node     Boards   Deactive) and (END). Each time we found them, The 1st line is the reference line. By adding the values of $1 for each record. Also, it will add $3,$4,$5&$7 if they were existed in the reference line. Then putting the data on column CSV format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to write the whole program for you, but maybe this will help you get started.

As I understand the problem, the interesting data lie between a header and a "stopper", and you'd like to convert a report format, where leading information is not repeated, to a table where it is.  That is, you want to pick up the announced Node on line one of each section, and substitute it at the beginning of each line of data.  And suppress blank lines while you're in the neighborhood.  Something like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f 

/^Node     Boards   Deactive/ {
    printing = 1
    print
    next
}

/^END/ {
    printing = 0
}

printing == 1 {
    printing = 2
    Node = $1
    print
    next
}

printing == 2 {
    leader = Node
    gsub(/[^ ]/, " ", leader)
    gsub("^" leader, Node)
    print
}
```

The last section constructs a string of blanks from the Node value, and substitutes the Node for it.

Getting this into CSV format is tedious because awk's regular expressions don't help you find data at fixed offsets.  I would make a separate script for that.  If you're using GNU awk, you may find FIELDWIDTHS helpful.  Either way, you'll have to count the columns or compute them using the header line.  I'd probably build an array of substrings based on those offsets, and print the array with OFS=",".

Comment: @JamesKLowden:Thanks for your support. I still have an issue. The script can be work for the file (Input_details.txt). But for the input file (input_all.txt) , the script is catches only the 1st value of Node (TSTS950) only. And repeat it every time till the end of the file.     The function gsub only repeat the value of TSTS950 on each line, and this is not OK.   You can find this point when you execute your script on both my input files. On the input file (input_all.txt), there are many Nodes between header and stopper. Till now, we couldn't catch them